# Jersey problem with URL binding to JSPs

Tags: java, jetty, jersey, web.xml

I am trying to bind URLs to JSPs via Jersey. I am trying to make a jokes website and I would like:

(1) /jokes = the list of jokes
(2) /jokes/213 = the page for joke with id 213

However, (2) does not seem to be working, I have no idea.

This is my web.xml with the jersey servlet

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.moesjokes.site.server.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Redirect</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.ImplicitViewables</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <!--<url-pattern>/jokes</url-pattern>-->
    <url-pattern>/jokes/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my resource:

```
    @Path("/")
public class Jokes {

  @GET
  @Path("/jokes")
  @Produces("application/xml")
  public Viewable getAll() {

    JspPage jsp = new JspPage(Pages.WELCOME);
    JspGlobalWidget global = jsp.getGlobal();

    JokesWidget jokes = new JokesWidget(jsp);
    jokes.setContents( new ContentServcies().getLatestContents(1, 20) );

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("jokes", jokes.toHtml());

    return new Viewable("/jsp/jokes/index.jsp", map);
  }


  @GET
  @Path("/jokes/{id}/*")
  @Produces("application/xml")
  public String get(@PathParam("id") String id) {

    return "<test>" + id + "</test>";
  }

}
```

Am I doing something wrong or ...? Im using Jetty 6.1, Jersey 1.6

Any help would be appreciate =)

Answer (score 1):

Change your path from

```
@Path("/jokes/{id}/*")
```

To

```
@Path("/jokes/{id}")
```

I don't believe that the former is in the correct format.

Comment: oi, if life could be so simple, ive tried to test that too. but at the end i will need {id}/* because the url will be /jokes/123/yo-mama-is-so-...

Comment: Ok.  Well, the former isn't in the correct format, specified here: http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/javax/ws/rs/Path.html . That said, try @Path("/jokes/{id}/{title}").